# regsub not working properly with string tolower

Tags: string, tcl, regsub

Im trying to make the first letter of that pattern lowercase.

```
 set filestr {"FooBar": "HelloWorld",}
 regsub -all {([A-Z])([A-Za-z]+":)} $filestr "[string tolower "\\1"]\\2" newStr
```

However the string tolower is not doing anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 2 step process in Tcl:

```
set tmp [regsub -all {([A-Z])([A-Za-z]+":)} $filestr {[string tolower "\1"]\2}]
```

```
"[string tolower "F"]ooBar": "HelloWorld",
```

Here we have added the *syntax* for lower casing the letter. Note how I have used non-interpolating braces instead of double quotes for the replacement part. Now we apply the `subst` command to actually *apply* the command:

```
set newStr [subst $tmp]
```

```
"fooBar": "HelloWorld",
```

Comment: One last thing if you dont mind. My strings have {, }, [, and ] in them, so doing this subst gives me a "missing close brace" etc. Is there a way to workaround this or should I try replacing all the brackets with something prior to doing this and then replace them back afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

In Tcl 8.7, you can do this in a single step with the new command substitution capability of `regsub`:

```
set filestr {"FooBar": "HelloWorld",}

# The backslash in the RE is just to make the highlighting here not suck
regsub -all -command {([A-Z])([A-Za-z]+\":)} $filestr {apply {{- a b} {
    string cat [string tolower $a] $b
}}} newStr
```

If you'd wanted to convert the entire word to lower case, you'd have been able to use this simpler version:

```
regsub -all -command {[A-Z][A-Za-z]+(?=\":)} $filestr {string tolower} newStr
```

But it doesn't work here because you need to match the whole word and pass it all through the transformation command; using lookahead constraints for the remains of the word allows those remains to be matched on the internal search for a match.